# how do controls in Magnolia 5.4 work?

Tags: controls, magnolia

I need to know how to work with controls in Magnolia 5.4. I've done the Hello Magnolia tutorial on their website and everything is ok, but I still have no idea how to use other controls because there is no article explaining it...

I hope some of you guys could help me out? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start [here](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/List+of+fields) to learn how to configure different fields (*control* is 4.x term, we use the term *field* since M5.0).

Answer (score 0):

How to add fields on a form is also documented in [Form definition](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Form+definition) and [My first content app](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/My+first+content+app#Myfirstcontentapp-Form).

Give feedback to the Magnolia documentation team. Describe what kind of tutorial would help you.